# Pushing WiFi configuration through Active Directory

Tags: windows, wifi, active-directory

I'm trying to push wifi settings to client computers through Active Directory, something that will add a defaul SSID to connect to and a WPA password. The only thing I've heard of is a script by Aruba labs called wificfg_xp.exe on a couple of forums ([Here](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/scripts/34952-script-joining-wireless-networks.html) and [here](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/11327/autoconfigure-windows-xp-laptops-novell-client-wpa-8021x-authentication)), but the [link](https://labs.arubanetworks.com/) to the download page is always broken. Does any one know of an alternative way to download this file, or another way to push these settings with AD?

Comment: What version of Windows Server?  What clients?

Comment: Oh, thanks, sorry I forgot to include that information. Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Group Policy and edit Computer Configuration, Windows Settings, Security Settings, and then click Wireless Network (IEEE 802.11) Policies.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg266419.aspx .

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be exactly what I was looking for!